# Creating subfolder for sendmail user

Tags: centos, email, sendmail, mailbox, rules

We use sendmail for automated email alerts such as info@compnayname.com or alerts@companyname.com. It's a simple sendmail configuration where these emails are created and then an alias is used to forward emails to whoever is in charge of looking at these mails. Those users then use outlook with pop3 to pull down these emails into their outlook to view these messages. So nothing stays on the server.

The problem is we also get a lot of spam sent to these emails as well. And one of our automated 3rd party system tools custom developed for us looks at one of these email and automatically generates tickets based on what comes to this email.

The issue is a lot of junk tickets are being created. To resolve this, i am being asked to create a folder within this mailbox and create a rule which will send all of the relevant emails into this folder. Then this automated tool will look inside this folder and generate tickets. This will reduce junk tickets in theory.

Does this make sesne? I want to know how i can create a folder within a sendmail user mailbox and create a rule to send emails to it based on subject rules.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Procmail can do what you ask.
Here's an example from the procmailex man page

```
Forward all mail from peter about compilers to william (and keep a copy of it here in petcompil).

          :0
          * ^From.*peter
          * ^Subject:.*compilers
          {
             :0 c
             ! william@somewhere.edu

             :0
             petcompil
          }
```

If you're not familiar with procmail, you can get going by reading this:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-email-mda.html#s2-email-procmail-configuration